# Proof that if $x<y$ then $x^s < y^s$ if $s\in Q$

Tags: real-analysis

My real analysis text presents this as a theorem and does not offer a proof. I was wondering if someone could explain how to prove this.

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers with $x<y,$ and let $s$
>   be a positive rational number then
>   $
> x^{s}<y^{s}
> $

Immediately prior to this theorem the text presents the following:

> Definition: Let $x$ be a positive real number and $n$ a positive integer. Then
>   $x^{1 / n}=\sqrt[n]{x}$ is that unique positive real number for which $\left(x^{1 / n}\right)^{n}=x$ .
>   Thus if $p$ and $q$ are positive integers, then $x^{p / q}=\left(x^{1 / q}\right)^{p} .$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that if $x\lt 1$ then $x^s\lt 1$ for any positive $s\in\mathbb Q$

Then $0\lt x\lt y\implies\frac{x}{y}\lt 1\implies (\frac{x}{y})^s\lt 1\implies x^s\lt y^s$

Comment: "...for any _positive_ $s\in\Bbb Q$."

Comment: @TonyK I fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove that if $n$ is an integer, $x,y>0$ and $x^n<y^n$ then $x<y.$ Set $z=\frac{y}{x}.$

Now, we have $z^n-1>0\Rightarrow (z-1)(\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}z^k)>0\Rightarrow z>1\Rightarrow y>x.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s=\frac{m}{n}$

Then $x^m<y^m$ since $\frac{y}{x}>1$

Now let $a=x^m$ and $b=y^m$

$$b^{\frac{1}{n}}-a^{\frac{1}{n}}=(b-a)\sum_{j=1}^nb^{\frac{n-j}{n}}a^{\frac{j-1}{n}}>0$$